# Struggling Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm new to Firestore Rules. All I want is simply check if user id exists within the object. Im reading data using `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` like so (query):

```
 Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection(EVENTS_INFO)
                .whereEqualTo("users." + user.getUid(), true);
```

Here is how structure looks in Firebase Console (screenshot):

[image]

Firestore rules here:

```
        service cloud.firestore {
           match /databases/{database}/documents {

              function isSignedIn() {
                 return request.auth.uid != null;
              }

              match /events/{event} {

                 function isUser() {
                    return isSignedIn() && resourse.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;
                 }

                 allow read: if isUser();
              }
           }
```

As there is no simulator I cant fast get the issue. `allow read: if true` works as desired. Any clues?

Comment: With the rules you've posted, we're not able to see where are these rules being applied to (which collection or document). Maybe it will be easier for us to help if you post the full rules

Comment: Please also post the code you're using to read the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with this line...

`resourse.data.users[request.auth.uid] == true;`

`resourse` should be written `resource`

Comment: Dollar sign is not allowed there. It seems that I misspelled resource. That was an issue. Please edit so I could accept.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  I just read the Rules Reference. I'll edit it now